# How to convert a python program to a Azure function?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

In my local, I created a time trigger function with python and every 5 minutes read a CSV file from blob storage and after processing, save it to another storage.

In local everything is okay. I "Deploy to Function APP..." from VS code to Azure but didn't work.

I wanna know how can I transfer this code to the Azure function?

```
 import datetime
 import logging
 import os
 import json
 import uuid
 import pandas as pd
 from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient, __version__
    
    
 import azure.functions as func
    
    
 def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
     utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
         tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()
    
     if mytimer.past_due:
         logging.info('The timer is past due!')
    
     logging.info('Python timer trigger function ran at %s', utc_timestamp)
    
     def clear_time(input_string):
         input_string = input_string.split(" ")
         date, time = input_string[0], input_string[1]
         time = time.split("-")[0].split(".")[0]
         return f"{date} {time}"
    
     def clean_iloc(input_line):
         temp = {}
         temp_array = []
         body = json.loads(input_line["body"])
         element_id = input_line["serial_id"]
         MSG_TYPE_TAG = body["MSG_TYPE_TAG"]
    
         # temp["serial_id"]=element_id
         # temp["message_type"]=MSG_TYPE_TAG
         temp_array.append(element_id)
         temp_array.append(MSG_TYPE_TAG)
         if body["error"] != {}:
             print(body["error"])
    
         if MSG_TYPE_TAG == "300":
             time = clear_time(
                 body["GET_RIGIDSENSE_SENSOR_ACCELDATA_LOG_TAG"]["date_time"])
             # temp["data_time"]=time
             temp_array.append(time)
             acceleration_array = body["GET_RIGIDSENSE_SENSOR_ACCELDATA_LOG_TAG"]["acceleration_array"]
             for i in range(100):
                 # temp[f"acceleration_element_{i}"]=acceleration_array[i]
                 temp_array.append(acceleration_array[i])
    
         else:
    
             time = clear_time(
                 body["GET_RIGIDSENSE_DEVICE_SHORTSTATUS_LOG_TAG"]["date_time"])
             # temp["data_time"]=time
             temp_array.append(time)
             for i in range(100):
                 # temp[f"acceleration_element_{i}"]=None
                 temp_array.append(None)
         return temp_array
    
     try:
    
         # Source Data Storage Variable
         urlblob = "******"
    
         # RAW Data Blob Storage Connection String
         raw_connect_str = "******"
    
         # Create the BlobServiceClient object which will be used to create a container client
         blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(
             raw_connect_str)
    
         # Create a unique name for the container
         container_name = str(uuid.uuid4())
    
         # Create the container
         container_client = blob_service_client.create_container(container_name)
         print("reading csv file...")
         df = pd.read_csv(urlblob)
         print("file read :D ")
    
         dataframe = pd.DataFrame({})
         dataframe["serial_id"] = []
         dataframe["message_type"] = []
         dataframe["data_time"] = []
         for i in range(100):
             dataframe[f"acceleration_element_{i}"] = []
         for i in range(df.shape[0]):
             dataframe.loc[i] = clean_iloc(df.iloc[i])
            
         # Create a blob client using the local file name as the name for the blob
         dataframe.to_csv("dataframe.csv")
         blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(
             container=container_name, blob='dataframe.csv')
         print("\nUploading to Azure Storage as blob:\t" + 'dataframe.csv')
         # Upload the created file
         with open("dataframe.csv", "rb") as data:
             blob_client.upload_blob(data)
    
     except Exception as ex:
         print('Exception:')
         print(ex)
```

Comment: Please describe "didn't work", otherwise we won't be able to work.

Comment: Any error output?

Comment: Please share your error output; or you can provide a Blob which can be processed, This can be helpful for us to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Peter Bons  I published this function on azure, and when I run all thing was okay but at the end of the code when the container created and blob didn't create. In my local, this code run and create dataframe.csv on the container but when publishing in the azure the dataframe.csv didn't create.

Comment: @BowmanZhu I explain the error

Comment: @FrankGong I explain the error

Comment: Could you please provide a Blob which can be processed, this can be helpful for us to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @FrankGong yes you can download sample dataset from this link. https://easyupload.io/rsnk7j

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use a temporary path to save the file, You can import tempfile and add this code in your function：

```
        # Create a blob client using the local file name as the name for the blob
        temp_path = tempfile.gettempdir()
        file_path = os.path.join(temp_path, 'dataframe.csv')
        dataframe.to_csv(file_path)
```

The final `Azure function` looks like this:

```
import datetime
import logging
import os
import json
import uuid
import pandas as pd
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient, __version__
import azure.functions as func
import tempfile


def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
        tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()

    if mytimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')

    logging.info('Python timer trigger function ran at %s', utc_timestamp)

    def clear_time(input_string):
        input_string = input_string.split(" ")
        date, time = input_string[0], input_string[1]
        time = time.split("-")[0].split(".")[0]
        return f"{date} {time}"

    def clean_iloc(input_line):
        temp = {}
        temp_array = []
        body = json.loads(input_line["body"])
        element_id = input_line["serial_id"]
        MSG_TYPE_TAG = body["MSG_TYPE_TAG"]

        # temp["serial_id"]=element_id
        # temp["message_type"]=MSG_TYPE_TAG
        temp_array.append(element_id)
        temp_array.append(MSG_TYPE_TAG)
        if body["error"] != {}:
            print(body["error"])

        if MSG_TYPE_TAG == "300":
            time = clear_time(
                body["GET_RIGIDSENSE_SENSOR_ACCELDATA_LOG_TAG"]["date_time"])
            # temp["data_time"]=time
            temp_array.append(time)
            acceleration_array = body["GET_RIGIDSENSE_SENSOR_ACCELDATA_LOG_TAG"]["acceleration_array"]
            for i in range(100):
                # temp[f"acceleration_element_{i}"]=acceleration_array[i]
                temp_array.append(acceleration_array[i])

        else:

            time = clear_time(
                body["GET_RIGIDSENSE_DEVICE_SHORTSTATUS_LOG_TAG"]["date_time"])
            # temp["data_time"]=time
            temp_array.append(time)
            for i in range(100):
                # temp[f"acceleration_element_{i}"]=None
                temp_array.append(None)
        return temp_array

    try:

        # Source Data Storage Variable
        urlblob = ""

        # RAW Data Blob Storage Connection String
        raw_connect_str = ""

        # Create the BlobServiceClient object which will be used to create a container client
        blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(
            raw_connect_str)

        # Create a unique name for the container
        container_name = str(uuid.uuid4())

        # Create the container
        container_client = blob_service_client.create_container(container_name)
        print("reading csv file...")
        df = pd.read_csv(urlblob)
        print("file read :D ")

        dataframe = pd.DataFrame({})
        dataframe["serial_id"] = []
        dataframe["message_type"] = []
        dataframe["data_time"] = []
        for i in range(100):
            dataframe[f"acceleration_element_{i}"] = []
        for i in range(df.shape[0]):
            dataframe.loc[i] = clean_iloc(df.iloc[i])
        
        # Create a blob client using the local file name as the name for the blob
        temp_path = tempfile.gettempdir()
        file_path = os.path.join(temp_path, 'dataframe.csv')
        dataframe.to_csv(file_path)
        blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(
            container=container_name, blob='dataframe.csv')
        print("\nUploading to Azure Storage as blob:\t" + 'dataframe.csv')
        # Upload the created file
        with open(file_path, "rb") as data:
            blob_client.upload_blob(data)

    except Exception as ex:
        print('Exception:')
        print(ex)
```